# Add multiple objects to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Every time I click an option of size and click add to cart I would like to add the data of the selected object to this array `cart`. This currently works kinda but only one object can be added and when you try to do it again the old data disappears and is replaced with the new object.

I would like to keep odd objects in the array and add new objects too. How do I go about doing this?

**index.js**

```
export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      evenSelected: null
    };
  }

  handleSelectL1 = i => {
    this.setState({
      evenSelected: i,
      oldSelected: null
    });
  };

  render() {
    const product = [
      {
        name: " size one",
        price: 1
      },
      {
        name: "size two",
        price: 2
      },
      ,
      {
        name: "size three",
        price: 3
      }
    ];

    const cart = [];

    const addCart = function() {
      cart.push(product[evenIndex]);
      if (cart.length > 0) {
      }
    };
    console.log("cart", cart);

    const evenIndex = this.state.evenSelected;
    const priceShown = product[evenIndex] && product[evenIndex].price;
    return (
      <div>
        <Child
          product={product}
          handleSelectL1={this.handleSelectL1}
          evenIndex={evenIndex}
        />
        <h2>Price:{priceShown} </h2>
        <button onClick={addCart}>Add to cart</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**child.js**

```
export class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const { product, evenIndex } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        {product.map((p, i) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={p.id}
              className={evenIndex === i ? "selectedRBox" : "selectorRBox"}
              onClick={() => this.props.handleSelectL1(i)}
            >
              <h1 className="selectorTextL">{p.name}</h1>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my code on sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/14vyy31nlj

Comment: You need to include the minimal code to reproduce your problem along with an example of the outcome you want in the question itself: links go dead, get stale, etc. I didn't dig into your code too much, but it looked...weird: this line `cart.concat(...cart);` doesn't do anything, nor is it clear what it's supposed to be doing, nor is that how you maintain state in react, etc.

Comment: Agree with @JaredSmith. `cart` is initialised every time render is called. Hence the array is getting cleared.

Comment: Oh ok, I just thought it would be easier as theres more than one file for it to be a link to the code. Yeah this line of code is redundant it was just me trying to figure out how to keep the old array and add the new object. How do I get it not to initialise every time render is called. Should it be outside of render?

Comment: Setup cart and product in the constructor rather than render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just modified your code to make it work. [Here is the complete code](https://codesandbox.io/s/9o7px46qly). You need cart to be part of the state, so it does not initialize in each render, and to make the component render again when you add an element.

Remove the function to make it a method of the class:

```
  addToCart() {
    const selectedProduct = products[this.state.evenSelected];
    this.setState({
      cart: [...this.state.cart, selectedProduct]
    });
  }
```

And call it on render:

```
  render() {
    console.log("cart", this.state.cart);
    const evenIndex = this.state.evenSelected;
    const priceShown = products[evenIndex] && products[evenIndex].price;
    return (
      <div>
        <Child
          product={products}
          handleSelectL1={this.handleSelectL1}
          evenIndex={evenIndex}
        />
        <h2>Price:{priceShown} </h2>
        <button onClick={this.addToCart.bind(this)}>Add to cart</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Check that I have binded on render, which can bring performance issues in some cases. You should [check this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36)

**Update**

As [devserkan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7060441/devserkan) made me notice (Thanks!), when you use the previous state to define the new state (for example adding an element to an array), it is better to use the `updater` function instead of passing the new object to merge:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  cart: [...prevState.cart, products[selectedProduct]],
}));
```

For more info [check the official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: Good answer though I would rather use a callback function in `setState` since we are using current state there.

Comment: @devserkan in this case I don't think that it could be a problem because you are calling the function once on each click. But good catch, I'll update my answer clarifying that.

Comment: Maybe it won't be a problem maybe will. This is how React people define this situation: if we don't use a callback it works by chance :) Here this is not a problem maybe, at worst array order changes. But whenever I see `this.state` in the `setState` method I remember this suggestion.

Comment: @devserkan you are right. I've updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks guys! An extended question - is the only way to do this is to have a function outside of render? What if I have modified `products` the array and I cannot call this outside of render. How can I have something similar to `addToCart()` inside of render?

Comment: @kadddeee you could define the function inside the render. It's just not necessary and not a good practice as it will instantiate a new function in each render.
I don't fully understand what you mean but maybe products should be passed as props to the component.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand what are you trying to but with a little change here it is. I've moved `product` out of the components like a static variable. Also, I've changed the `addCart` method, set the state there without mutating the original one and keeping the old objects.

```js
const product = [
  {
    name: " size one",
    price: 1
  },
  {
    name: "size two",
    price: 2
  },
  {
    name: "size three",
    price: 3
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      evenSelected: null,
      cart: [],
    };
  }

  handleSelectL1 = i => {
    this.setState({
      evenSelected: i,
      oldSelected: null
    });
  };

  addCart = () => {
    const evenIndex = this.state.evenSelected;
    this.setState( prevState => ({
      cart: [ ...prevState.cart, product[evenIndex] ],
    }))
  };

  render() {
  console.log(this.state.cart);
    const evenIndex = this.state.evenSelected;
    const priceShown = product[evenIndex] && product[evenIndex].price;
    return (
      <div>
        <Child
          product={product}
          handleSelectL1={this.handleSelectL1}
          evenIndex={evenIndex}
        />
        <h2>Price:{priceShown} </h2>
        <button onClick={this.addCart}>Add to cart</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const { product, evenIndex } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        {product.map((p, i) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={p.id}
              className={evenIndex === i ? "selectedRBox" : "selectorRBox"}
              onClick={() => this.props.handleSelectL1(i)}
            >
              <h1 className="selectorTextL">{p.name}</h1>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.selectorRBox {
  width: 260px;
  height: 29.5px;
  border: 1px solid #727272;
  margin-top: 18px;
}

.selectedRBox {
  width: 254px;
  height: 29.5px;
  margin-top: 14px;
  border: 4px solid pink;
}

.selectorTextL {
  font-family: "Shree Devanagari 714";
  color: #727272;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is essentially it too :)